# Запрос SQL. Изменение данных из таблице при INSERT в другой

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Столкнулся с очень сложным для меня запросом: есть таблица Products, в которой есть столбец Amount. Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении нового заказа в таблице Orders, уменьшался этот столбец, на количество, которое берется из другой таблицы Compositions. Так как запись в Orders содержит несколько несколько разных Courses в одной строке, нужно иметь несколько JOIN`s, которые будут изменять Amount для каждого Courses добавленного в Orders. Связь получается такая: Orders.First(ID) => Courses.ID => Composition.ID(тут блюдо разделяется на 2 продукта, количество которых нужно изменить) => Produts.Amount.

Orders

```
id | date | userid | first | second | etc
-------------------------------------
1  |    - |     -  |    1  |     2  |
```

Courses

```
courseid |      name      | price | compositionid |
--------------------------------------------------
    1    | chicken & fish |   20  |       1
    1    | chicken & beef |   20  |       2
```

Compositions

```
id | firstproductid | firstproductamount | secondproduct | secondproductamount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |       1        |         100        |      2        |         50
 2 |       1        |         50         |      3        |         100
```

Products

```
prdocutid | amount |
--------------------
    1     |  1000  |
    2     |  1000  |
    3     |  1000  |
```

т.е. после добавление в Orders данных под id 1 - таблица Products должна изменится:

```
prdocutid | amount |
--------------------
    1     |  850   |
    2     |  950   |
    3     |  900   |
```

Comment: Нахрена оно тебе? это ж до первого сбоя, а дальше у тебя в таблице будет полная лажа, которую ты уверенно будешь считать истиной... Есть приход, есть расход - соответственно баланс считается одним простейшим запросом.

Comment: "_Так как запись в Orders содержит несколько несколько разных Courses в одной строке_". Такого быть не должно в принципе. Это нарушает 1НФ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0 Как следствие работать с таблицей становиться очень сложно. Необходимо сначала разделить таблицу Orders на 2, что бы first second и т.п. стали отдельными строками. То же самое скорее всего касается и Compositions

Comment: Сколько работал номальных форм ни разу не встречал. Всегда были излишки данных, только ради  оптимизации запросов.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Ради оптимизации да, бывает приходиться нарушать. Но когда в таблице колонки first, second и походу их еще больше и надо писать столько же join про слово "оптимизация" можно сразу забыть